# Error on installation - own developed Microsoft Office C# VSTO Addin

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

we write our first outlook addin with vsto (visual studio tools for office).

It works on my PC. On other PCs we get a security exception in the installation process (german):

> System.Security.SecurityException: enutzerdefinierte Funktionen können
>   in dieser Anwendung nicht verwendet werden, weil das Zertifikat, mit
>   dem das Bereitstellungsmanifest für Foobar.OutlookAddin signiert wurde,
>   oder sein Speicherort nicht vertrauenswürdig sind. Wenden Sie sich an
>   den Administrator, um weitere Unterstützung zu erhalten.
>
> bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustPromptKeyInternal(ClickOnceTrustPromptKeyValue
>   promptKeyValue, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation,
>   String productName, TrustStatus status)
>
> bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInTrustEvaluator.VerifyTrustUsingPromptKey(Uri
>   manifest, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation, String
>   productName, TrustStatus status)
>
> bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.ProcessSHA2Manifest(ActivationContext
>   context, DeploymentSignatureInformation signatureInformation,
>   PermissionSet permissionsRequested, Uri manifest,
>   ManifestSignatureInformationCollection signatures,
>   AddInInstallationStatus installState, TrustStatus sha256TrustStatus,
>   X509Certificate2 sha256PublisherCert)
>
> bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.VerifySecurity(ActivationContext
>   context, Uri manifest, AddInInstallationStatus installState)
>
> bei
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.ClickOnceAddInDeploymentManager.InstallAddIn()
>
> Die Zone der Assembly, bei der ein Fehler aufgetreten ist:
>
> MyComputer

Anybody knows what´s the problem and how i prevent it?

I think it´s a topic with the certification process. Actual we haven´t a own certificate. But when we buy it, our problem will solved?

Comment: What is that long first exception message in English?

Comment: corresponding: "The deployment manifest or the install location is not trustable"

Answer (score 3):

Ensure that the ClickOnce trust prompt is enabled for the zone from which you are trying to load the customization. Navigate to the below registry key and ensure that the PromptingLevel is set to Enabled for the zone from where you are trying to load the customization.

On 32 bit machines:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT.NETFramework\Security\TrustManager\PromptingLevel

On 64 bit machines:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MICROSOFT.NETFramework\Security\TrustManager\PromptingLevel

For more information, visit [How to: Configure Inclusion List Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772070.aspx).

If you are installing the customization from a web site, then make sure that the site is added to the trusted sites.

You may find the following links helpful:

- [Troubleshooting common VSTO issues – Part 1](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/09/17/troubleshooting-common-vsto-issues-part-1/)
- [Troubleshooting common VSTO issues – Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2012/10/08/troubleshooting-common-vsto-issues-part-2/)

Comment: Thank you! Now we get another error and could work with the troubleshooting issues part 2 to fix it.

Comment: I'd recommend marking the post as answer if it helped to address the issue.

Comment: Despite having x64 machine, changing the path for x32 machines helped me to solve the problem unlike changing the path for x64

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your add-in doesn't be registered in the computer deployed.
When you deploy your VSTO in the different computers, you should insert some keys in the Windows Registry with the Admin right.

For example, if your computer is x64 bit, you can insert (ideally with the location of the VSTO in disk C:)

```
  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\Addins\your-addin-name]

    "Description"="your-addin-name" 
    "FriendlyName"="your-addin-name"
    "Manifest"="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft
     Office\\Outlook\\Addins\\your-addin-name\\your-addin-name.vsto|vstolocal"
    "LoadBehavior"=dword:00000003
```

It works for my add-in deployed in 500 computers x64 bit with a self certificate

Comment: Should this part not be done by the setup? We start the setup and it fails with the error on top.

Comment: In my case, because the setup will not insert correctly these keys in my answer. You should ensure manually these keys exist in the right location. If not, an exception will raised when your addin start and Outlook put it in disactived list